# Performance of the fuzzy c-means clustering algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, matlab, optimization

I have implemented a genetic algorithm for a fuzzy c-means clustering in Matlab. Its performance should be apriori better than that of the classic fuzzy c-means (fcm function in matlab). However, on all the classical datasets I am comparing them, both algorithms converge to the same value of the objective function.

My question is the following: is it just my bad luck, or FCM usually converges to the global minimum? Are there any datasets known when FCM shows suboptimal performance?

Thanks,

Comment: Why not compare your results in a dataset where you already know the correct clusters beforehand?  Alternatively you could compare both the algorithms with another clustering algorithm not based on FCM.